Understanding Stack Frames and Stack Layout in Function Calls on x86 Systems
I'm currently exploring stack frames and how they work in C programs, specifically on unprotected 32-bit x86 systems (no ASLR, stack canaries, or DEP). I'm not primarily a CS Student — I'm a physics student taking an additional IT security course out of personal curiosity. Since the following is a prerequisite topic, it wasn’t covered extensively in my lectures, and I don't have colleagues at hand to turn to for questions, so I’m hoping to get some insights here!
Here’s the simple C program I’m experimenting with:
void vulnerable_function(int input) {
  int secret = input;
  char buffer[8];

  //stop execution here looking at stack layout

  gets(buffer);
  if (secret == 0x41424344) {
    printf("Access granted!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Access denied!\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  vulnerable_function(0x23);
  return 0;
}


What does the stack frame look like when the execution is stopped in the vurnerable_func Specifically, how are the return address, saved base pointer, and local variables (secret and buffer) arranged on the stack before gets(buffer); is called? From my current understanding, the stack should look from low Memory addresses to high: 0x00000000 --> [free]; [buffer]; [secret]; [saved EBP]; [RET]; [input]; [main stack frame] --> 0xFFFFFFFF?

How are function arguments generally placed on the stack? Is the argument (input in this case) always placed on the stack first, followed by the return address, saved base pointer, and then space for local variables?

How can an input to gets(buffer); overwrite the secret variable? What kind of input would cause the program to print "Access granted!" Would it be possible to input: \x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x42\x43\x44 or "AAAAAAAAABCD" ? since 0x41 is A and the buffer is 8 bytes in the main to get the desired result by overriding secret through a buffer overflow?

Regarding stack canaries, where are they generally placed? Are they typically placed right after the saved base pointer (EBP): [buffer] [canary] [saved EBP] [return address]?


I’d really appreciate any explanations or pointers to resources that cover stack memory layout, how function calls work at a low level!
Thanks in advance for your help!

If the compiler places secret before buffer in memory, with difficulty. There is no requirnent to place variables in the same sequence as you write them.

Buffer overflow attacks depend on the layout generated by specific compilers.

@WeatherVane While not required, exploits take advantage of the consistency of typical compilers.


depends on the calling convention, about which the C Standard has nothing to say.



yes, unless compiled with a convention that passes some args in registers, like MSVC fastcall or GCC regparm(3).  The default calling conventions for 32-bit x86 do indeed all pass args on the stack, right above the return address.  (Unlike Windows x64 where there are 4 register args, and stack args go above the shadow space.)



The CPU itself does not require a specific structure of the stack frame. A stack can be seen as a global array accessible via the esp and registers are global variables (in some cases with special meanings). The structure of a stack frame is specified by the operating system, because a program can only be executed at all if all programs follow to a convention. These are so-called “calling conventions”. These differ between the various operating systems (and whether you are in 32 or 64 bit mode), so it is not possible to give you a general idea of what the stack frame looks like. Here is the Wikipedia article for this topic.

Possible stack frame after the function "vurnerable_func" was called:
<High addresses>
...
[old ebp]
[input]
[return address]


If we assume the cdecl convention (this is widespread in 32 bit mode), then the variables of a function are saved in reverse order on the stack before the function is called. In this case: yes the return address, function parameters and local variables are on the stack. However, this does not have to be the case with other calling conventions.

As already indicated in the comments: You have no guarantees at all where exactly the C variables are located. Local variables are often located on the stack. But whether this is the case here - and whether the order is the same as in the C code - is not specified.
Assuming that the order of the C variables is that in the source code and there are on the stack, then yes: with “AAAAAAAAAAABCD” you would overwrite the local variable secret.

Where the stack canaries are located is also not standardized across platforms. They are often located directly before the return address:


<High addresses>
[old ebp]
[input]
[return address]
[canary]

Here is a minimal example of what a function call looks like in the cdecl convention.
C-Code:
int func(int var1, int var2)
{
    return var1 + var2;
}
    
int main(void)
{
    int var = func(5, 10);
    return 0;
}

Possible x86 assembly code:
main:
    ; Create stack frame
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Push the variables in opposite order on the stack
    push 10
    push 5

    call func

    ; Because the stack grows from up to down: add 8 to bring the stack pointer on the positon before the variables were pushed onto the stack
    add esp, 8

    ; Destroy stack frame
    ; Restore stack pointer before the stack frame was created
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ; Result of the function is in eax
    ; Do something with it ...

    xor eax, eax ; By convention a program gives it exit status in eax. Meaning of 0: no errors
    ret
    
func:
    ; Via the esp the function parameters can be addressed
    ; "+ 4" is important, because due to the call func parameter the return address is onto the stack
    ; So jump over the return address and work with the function parameter
    mov eax, [esp + 4]
    add eax, [esp + 8]

    ; Using the return address
    ret

It is important to keep in mind that there are multiple possibilities to create and destroy a stack frame. The online tool Compiler explorer is a nice tool the discover the generated assembler code. It depends massively on the compiler used, the options and the operating system how the code looks.

Mostly a good answer, but no sane compiler is going to turn var1 + var2 into an xor-zero plus two adds.  (Even if you wrote it as 0  + var1 + var2 which you didn't).  Compilers would just mov eax, [esp+4] / add eax, [esp+8] or vice versa.  Like GCC and Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/qh3P8K1Kh

Fun fact: gcc -fstack-protector-strong will put arrays at higher addresses in the stack frame than scalar variables, so you can't just overwrite secret with a buffer overflow that stops short of the canary or return address.  https://godbolt.org/z/1EezcTe7P - I had to build with no optimization (-O0) for secret to have its own memory address instead of just optimizing away to reading the stack arg.  But with -fstack-protector-strong it's at [ebp-24] below the array at [ebp-20].  Otherwise it's at [ebp-12], above the array ([ebp-20]) where OP expects, with GCC 14.2 for Linux.

Of course compilers are free to create any kind of code that creates the expected result. Especially with the xor eax, eax operation. I tried to write down the most intuitive and understandable way to translate the C code.

Separate from efficiency, one add better reflects a C expression with one + operation so your updated version is more intuitive.  (And yes, agreed that being intuitive / matching the C in an obvious way is more important for this answer than efficiency or what compilers actually do, but in this case it's both.)
